# Upgrading from Esri.Arcgis.Client 10.2.x to Arcgis.Runtime.100.x

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net, esri-arc-engine

Hello fellow arcgis developers.
I am about to migrate from old Arcgis.Client .Net to Arcgis.Runtime .Net.
And looking at the documentation I cant find what corresponding namespaces they are now using in the Arcgis.Runtime 100.x.

Now when running Arcgis.Client i have these all namespace i need to change for the corresponding in Arcgis.Runtime 100.13 and as i mentioned could not find in the documentation:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Local;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry;
```

I have been looking at this guide but I dont mention the namepaces above.
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/reference/migrate-to-100-x-from-10-2-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a 1:1 but most namespaces are under Esri.ArcGISRuntime.* instead of Esri.ArcGIS.Client.*. Let intellisense and auto complete in Visual Studio help you discover them. Also not all classes are 1:1 so they might be named different or use a completely different and improved approach now